# Unset Read Only Variables

Tags: aix, ksh, readonly

Is it possible to unset or change a `readonly` variable in Korn Shell? I am using AIX 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know of. At least, the obvious ways won't work: you can't `unset` a readonly variable or remove the readonly attribute with `typeset +r`. This goes for all the ksh variants that I've seen, and for bash, but there are apparently ksh versions such as [on AIX 4.3](http://www.linuxmisc.com/12-unix-web-servers/c6772e98d5cf72d5.htm) that allow `typeset +r` (which zsh also allows).

Technically, you can do this from outside: connect to the ksh process with a debugger and flip the bit in memory where the ksh process stores the information that the variable is read-only. So a readonly variable is not an absolute security feature.

If you need to set a variable to a different value before launching a command, do it through `env`:

```
readonly foo='some value'
env foo='other value' mycommand
```

Alternatively, make the variable read-only in a restricted scope (in a function).

Comment: Gilles, you teach me something new everyday here :-)